# nm-applet (the little computer) does not show up in my system tray after a fresh install of Debian Jessie Beta 2

Tags: debian, wifi, usb, usb-drive, networkmanager

I just installed Jessie Beta 2 using the amd64 DVD images, rather than netinst images, and fresh out of the box, nm-applet doesn't show up in the system tray. The little computer right next to the notification area that lists networks, etc. is just not there. I tried alt-F2 "nm-applet" but nothing happens. I've tried logging out and logging back in.

How can I get nm-applet to show up, so I can actually use it?

Comment: Is the network manager service running?

Comment: And run it from a terminal and see what happens.